# Russian National Ice-Hockey Team

Tags: olympics, ice-hockey, nhl

I've seen Russia lose its match in the Olympics (2014). From the commentators on the television, I was informed that many of them play in the NHL and are millionaires.

How many do play in the NHL and are in fact millionaires?

Comment: Millionaire in terms of USD or [Russian Rubles](https://www.google.com/search?q=russian+currency+to+us+dollar&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=sb)?

Comment: @edmastermind29 didn't I mention Bitcoins?

Comment: Oh, virtual millionaires. Got it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### How many do play in the NHL?

The roster consists of 25 players total for the Russian Men's National ice hockey team. Of those 25 players, 16 of them are in the NHL. The remaining 9 play in the [Russian Superleague (KHL)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kontinental_Hockey_League).

---

### How many are millionaires?

Well, I guess this is a tough question to answer. Most likely, all of them are millionaires to some degree. Certain players like Malkin, Ovechkin, etc., certainly are making *way* more money than most of their other teammates. But, if you take a look at the players' Wiki pages, contract information is generally given there about each one. The players in the KHL's contract information doesn't appear on their Wiki pages as often; however, I remember one of the announcers rambling on about how much money [Radulov makes in the KHL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_Radulov#Return_to_KHL) ($9.2m/year), and considering the popularity of the sport in Russia, it's probably a safe bet to say all the players on their Olympic squad are millionaires.